# After deployment of web jquery is giving error output its working on local

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

what am I doing wrong?

```
<form id="contact-form"  method="POST">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-box user-icon mb-30">
                <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-box email-icon mb-30">
                <input type="email" id="Email"  placeholder="Your Email">
                <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-box phone-icon mb-30">
                <input type="number" id="Phone"  placeholder="Your Phone">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-box subject-icon mb-30">
                <input type="text" id="Subject"  placeholder="Your Subject">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-box message-icon mb-30">
                <textarea item id="Message"  cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-icon ml-0" id="submit"  type="submit" >Send Message <i class="far fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is html form where i used id for get data from User and using ajex post method i try to send an email but after submit the form the jquery giving an error as below

```
<p>undefinedfunction(){return s&&(t&&!i&&(l=s.length-1,u.push(t)),function n(e){S.each(e,function(e,t){m(t)?r.unique&&f.has(t)||s.push(t):t&&t.length&&"string"!==w(t)&&n(t)})}(arguments),t&&!i&&c()),this}</p>

        <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var name = $('#Name').val();
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var phone = $('#Phone').val();
        var subject = $('#Subject').val();
        var message = $('#Message').val();
        if (name == "") {
            swal('Please Enter Your Name')
            return false
        }
        if (email == "") {
            swal('Please Enter Your Email')
            return false
        } 
        if (phone == "") {
            swal('Please Enter Your Phone')
            return false
        }
        if (subject == "") {
            swal('Please Enter Your Subject')
            return false
        }
        if (message == "") {
            swal('Please Enter Your Message')
            return false
        }
      
       if(name!=""||email!=""||phone!=""||subject!=""||message!=""){
            $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Contact","Home")",
            type:"Post",
            data: {
                Name:name,
                Email:email,
                Phone:phone,
                Subject:subject,
                Message:message
            },
            success: function(e) {
               
                swal('Email Send Successfully. Our Team Contact You Soon...');
            },
            error: function(e) {
              swal(e.error);
            }
        })
       }
    })
})</script>
```

jquery which is giving error not success after deployment its working on local

[image: Error on submit form using jquery]

https://janai.umrershikshan.com/Home/Contact
this is side where is form after click on send message its giving error

Comment: I see its throwing 500 error from the server. I suggest to put some logs on your action method

Comment: You should  add something like `asp-controller` and `asp-action`, I havn't seen anything in this `form`, so it will post the data to the current page. See Debug details [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9tMO.png) and [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4EvO.png). Or you are missing post method about `/Home/Contact`.

Comment: @Jason it is working on local but after deployment it is not working. and data is posting using Id as in jquery